# Compile all source files into executables

Tags: shell, makefile

I know that makefile is used for a project where files are related. But I want to use it in a different way.

Since I always write lots of test files, I need to type a bunch of flags every time I compile them, that's so troublesome. I just want to write a makefile that compiles all source files into executables with their corresponding names - like `a.c` to `a` and `b.c` to `b`, etc. so that I can get executables by simply typing make instead of the whole gcc ...

Is there any simple way to do it?

Comment: Learn scripting. It's really simple and beneficial. I can show you mine if you want. I created a makefile that compiles all the times

Comment: @KRUKUSA Yes I will learn scripting soon but for now I am learning C and still very new. So I need this to improve efficiency :). It'd be great if you can share yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make has a built in implicit rule like this:

```
  % : %.c
         $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<
```

$(CFLAGS) would contain all your options.

Then, doing

```
make foo
```

Would try to produce foo from foo.c (if it existed).

To be able to compile all of them in one go, add another rule:

```
all: $(patsubst %.c,%,$(wildcard *.c))
```

This new rule, called 'all', has the list of your executables as its prerequisite. The wildcard function lists all .c files in the directory, and the patsubst removes the .c from each of them, leaving a list of the executables that would be produced from each .c file.

So doing

```
make all
```

causes it to try to compile each .c file into the corresponding executable.

Comment: I understand most of it, but confused of the prerequisite of all. What does patsubst do? Isn't * already implying wildcard? Why do you need to add 'wildcard' in front of it?

Comment: @Xufeng OK, have edited to explain that a bit better

Answer (score 0):

Alright understood. I'm not too sure if you'll understand the syntax. I'll try to explain as much as I can.

you'll make a file called Makefile no extensions.

```
DIR=$(HOME)/../"Your directory"

all: "Whatever driver you may have"

purify: purify g++ -o "Your file" -Wall -pedantic -g "objective file .o extension"

# Makes clean file
clean:
        rm -f *.o  "Drivers"

new:
    make clean
    make
```

Comment: what does purify do? why do you need that before the compiler name? Also, do I need to explicitly replace "Your file" with the name of the output file I want? I want the makefile to generate its name automatically actually.

Comment: Yes. Purify checks for memory leaks in case if you want to run valgrind

Comment: This has all kinds of problems.  I wouldn't use it as an example.

Answer (score 0):

`make` has built in implicit rules to do that.  Just type `make a` or `make b` or `make a b` or whatever you want.  Add and export an environment variable called `CFLAGS` if you want to add any special options.